# His "get-up-and-go" is likely to have "got-up-and-gone" Any hidden meaning in this comment?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, american-english

I once overheard a conversation between two young women on a long distance flight and one of them said: "He is past seventy, you know. His get-up-and-go is likely to have got-up-and gone." And they both laughed.  That was the only time I ever heard such phrases. I checked some dictionaries and found "get-up-and-go" = energy, ambition, whereas my search for "got-up-and-gone" found nothing. The way the two women laughed makes me wonder: does "get-up-and-go" have a real sexual connotation which the dictionaries omit, or is it an opinion-based, context-related interpretation?

Comment: Although "got up and gone" is not something you'd find in dictionaries, the play on words (as described in Amadan's answer) [is well established in folk songs and self-help blogs](https://www.google.ca/#q=%22got+up+and+gone%22+%22get+up+and+go%22).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old joke based on the idiomatic phrase "get-up-and-go" (which is typically defined as you have found).  The most notable variant is probably from the well-known humorous poem ["My Get Up and Go Has Got Up and Went](http://holyjoe.org/poetry/anon7.htm)" (later set to music by Pete Seeger) but I imagine the witticism precedes it.

It's not unlikely that the women you overheard intended it with a sexual connotation, but then, most things can be intended in such a way if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 3):

I would just say they laughed at the clever word-play; to me, the sentence basically means "He likely doesn't have the energy he used to have when he was younger any more". Just like this paraphrase, and just like the words *energetic* or *virile*, it could, but does not have to, carry a sexual undertone.

*Got-up-and-gone* is not an idiom, it is just a past tense rendering of the idiom *get-up-and-go* interpreted non-idiomatically (i.e. "stood up and went away" rather than "was energetic/ambitious").

Comment: The late great Pete Seeger had a [song about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdNQt4a6f7g), using the variant "my get-up-and-go has got up and went."